# Is there any difference with undefined behaviour between iterator and scalar object?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

[The topic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) about evaluation order says that following code leads to undefined behavior until C++17:

```
a[i] = i++;
```

This happens due to unspecified order while evaluating left and right parts of the assignment expression.

C++14 standard 1.9/15 says:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, and they are not potentially concurrent (1.10), the behavior is undefined.

But what if we use `std::vector` and its `iterator` object instead of scalar object `i`?

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2};
auto it = v.begin();
*it = *it++;   // UB?
```

Is there undefined behaviour (until c++17) or not?

Comment: The iterator is *allowed* to be a raw pointer, and could get you into trouble. If it is a class object, the operators are function calls which introduce sequence points (in all standard revisions).

Comment: @BoPersson so we can't be sure is there UB or not by the Standard?

Comment: This is specific to vector where a pointer would work as an iterator. On known implementations it is not, partly to allow debug iterators to store extra state. Also, even if  `*it = *it++;` would work, it would perhaps do `*it = *it; ++it;` and not be very useful anyway. Most borderline code is like that - hard to see what it does, and only marginally useful.

Comment: If any feasible implementation of vector can have a iterator for which this yields undefined behaviour,  the behaviour is undefined in general.   One possible outcome of undefined behaviour is an implementation choice in which the outcome is actually well defined.

Comment: @BoPersson Will there be any changes in behavior if I put function over rhs: `*it = f(*it++);`?

Comment: I don't know. It definitely *does* introduce a function call making `*it++` be fully evaluated before the call to `f`. However, before C++17 I suspect that the left hand side could still be evaluated either before or after the increment. So I never write code like this.

Comment: To clarify (if I'm understanding this correctly), C++17 still leaves the order of evaluation unspecified, so `a[i] = i++;` is not a good idea.  C++17 just rules out nasal demons, and guarantees that you will assign `old_i` to either `a[old_i]` or `a[new_i]`.  There may be cases where either order is fine, and leaving it up to the compiler to choose is what you want.  (e.g. `f(++i, ++i)` where `f(a,b)` is commutative.)  C++17 lets you write that safely.  But `n = ++i + i;` is still fully UB in C++17.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In situations when an iterator is a class, the behavior is well defined in all versions of the standard, assuming that `it++` points to a valid location inside its container (which in your example it does).

C++ translates `*it++` to this sequence of two function calls:

```
it.operator++(0).operator*();
```

Function calls introduce sequencing, so all side effects of the actual `++` invoked inside `operator++` on the primitive used as an iterator's implementation (probably, a raw pointer) must complete before the function exit.

However, iterators are not required to be classes: they could be pointers, too:

```
struct foo {
    typedef int* iterator;
    iterator begin() { return data; }
private:
    int data[10];
};
```

The code looks the same, and it continues to compile, but now the behavior is undefined:

```
foo f;
auto it = f.begin();
*it = *it++; // <<== This is UB
```

You can guard against this by invoking `++` as a member function:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2};
auto it = v.begin();
*it = *it.operator++(0);
```

When the iterator is actually a pointer, this code will fail to compile, rather than causing undefined behavior.

Comment: If I use `f(*it++)` on the right side, will UB gone even for raw pointer implementation?

Comment: @alexolut Yes, all side effects of argument expression evaluations take effect before the function is entered.

Comment: Aren't you assuming C++17 rule "left side of (compound-)assignment is sequenced after right side? Granted, it's only unspecified behavior due to indeterminate sequencing not undefined behavior, but still.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hmm, but the order of evaluation of the left and right sides is still unsequenced. I.e. `*it` (lhs) could be evaluated before or after function call on the right side. Hence still UB. Am I right?